# Trying to retrieve TFS workitems using ClientService.asmx

Tags: web-services, soap

I am trying to retrieve TFS workitems using ClientService.asmx using JavaScript and I am able to access the webservice, however when using the SOAP it gives me following error "TF51612: The query does not contain any groups or expressions.
Parameter name: queryXml"

Below is the code that I am using to access the Workitems:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
  <RequestHeader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/WorkItemTracking/ClientServices/03">
  <Id></Id>
  </RequestHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
  <QueryWorkitems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/WorkItemTracking/ClientServices/03">
  <psQuery>
  <queryXml>
  <Wiql>SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project  AND  [System.WorkItemType] &lt;&gt; ''  AND  [System.State] &lt;&gt; '' ORDER BY [System.Id] </Wiql>
  </queryXml>
  </psQuery>
  </QueryWorkitems>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your header SOAP must contais informations about your credential, because your query header's is empty so you are not authenticated

Add this with Soap Extension in your Web service, register in config file

Comment: SOAP is getting authenticated at runtime, the error that i get is for the Query Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

After much pain I figured out how to do a proper request to this service. Here is my full request. Forgive me for the formatiing. I am apparently too dumb to figure out how to do a proper list.

Couple of notes...

*the RequestHeader Id field has to be in the format uuid:GUID

*The psQuery element is not actually in Wiql as other web sources have hinted. (Which is you are receiving the error)

*The FieldType for numeric fields is 288

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/WorkItemTracking/ClientServices/03">
<soapenv:Header>
<ns:RequestHeader>
<!--Optional:-->
<ns:Id>uuid:262c6910-8394-11e3-baa7-0800200c9a67</ns:Id>
</ns:RequestHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:QueryWorkitems>
<!--Optional:-->
<ns:psQuery>
<Group GroupOperator="And">
<Expression Column="System.TeamProject" FieldType="16" Operator="equals"><String>ProjectName</String></Expression>
<Expression Column="System.AssignedTo" FieldType="16" Operator="equals"><String>Daniel West</String></Expression>
<Expression Column="System.WorkItemType" FieldType="16" Operator="equals"><String>Anomaly</String></Expression>
<Expression Column="System.State" FieldType="16" Operator="equals"><String>Validate</String></Expression>   
</Group>
</ns:psQuery>
<ns:sort>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<ns:QuerySortOrderEntry>
<!--Optional:-->
<ns:ColumnName>System.AssignedTo</ns:ColumnName>
<ns:Ascending>1</ns:Ascending>
</ns:QuerySortOrderEntry>
</ns:sort>
<ns:useMaster>1</ns:useMaster>
</ns:QueryWorkitems>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```